# userscript для игры

Tags: javascript

пишу юзерскрипт для игры... суть в следующем: нужно ожидать определенное количество времен, после чего обновить страницу и перейти по ссылке..

закинул в виде расширения в chrome.

на одной вкладке работает сносно..
но при открытии нескольких вкладок на какой-либо из вкладок может проскочить момент перехода по ссылке..
то есть обновление прошло, а перейти не успело - таймер пошел заново.
в чем может заключаться проблема?

код скрипта

```
    function timer() {
    setTimeout(update, 2000);
}

function update() {
    localStorage.setItem("clickOnLink", "1");
    location.reload(true);
}



function FindByAttributeValue() {


    var All = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < All.length; i++) {

        if (/\.*Персонаж\.*/.test(All[i].innerHTML)) {
            return All[i]
        }
    }
}

function goLink() {

    var link = FindByAttributeValue();
    if (link === undefined) {
        alert("Ссылка не найдена");
        timer();
    }
    localStorage.setItem("clickOnLink", "2");

    window.location.href = link.href;
}

window.onload = function () {

    var item = localStorage.getItem("clickOnLink");
    if (item === null) {
        timer();
    }
    localStorage.removeItem("clickOnLink");

    switch (item) {
        case "1":
            {
                goLink();
                break;
            }
        case "2":
            {
                timer();
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что все вкладки используют один и тот же ключ `"clickOnLink"`.

Comment: А как его сделать уникальным для каждой вкладки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что все вкладки используют один и тот же ключ `"clickOnLink"`.

Если это функциональность нужна Вам работающей параллельно в нескольких табах браузера, есть вариант передавать этот флаг через url: `#click1`, `#click2`.

---

```
  function timer() {
    setTimeout(update, 2000);
}

function update() {
    var parts = location.href.split("#");
    location.href = parts[0] + "#click1";
    location.reload(true);
}

function FindByAttributeValue() {
    var All = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < All.length; i++) {

        if (/\.*Персонаж\.*/.test(All[i].innerHTML)) {
            return All[i]
        }
    }
}

function goLink() {

    var link = FindByAttributeValue();
    if (link === undefined) {
        alert("Ссылка не найдена");
        timer();
    }

    window.location.href = link.href + "#click2";

}

window.onload = function () {

    var item = location.hash;
    if (item == "#click1") {
        goLink();
    } else {
        timer();
    }

}
```

Comment: можн подробнее?

Comment: так должно быть?

Comment: @EwgenyKokoshko похоже на правду. Оно делает то, что Вам надо?

Comment: если считать за одну итерацию обновление + переход по ссылке, то скрипт делает две итерации и останавливается

Comment: заканчивается на ссылке с хешем click2

Comment: как я понял, дело в строке location.href = link.href + "#click2";   переход по этой ссылке во второй раз уже не осуществляется потому, что это текущая страница и location.href == link.href, есть ли способ форсировать переход по ссылке?

Comment: @EwgenyKokoshko Это легко решить проверкой текущего `location.href` и вызовом `location.reload`.

Comment: именно так и сделал, спасибо

Comment: а почему в выражении location.href = parts[0] + "#click2";
    location.reload(); происходит обновление страницы, хотя первым стоит переход по ссылке